# Как сделать WhatsApp звонок из приложения Android

Tags: java, android

На просторах en-SO нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674897/5634351) , в комментариях сказано что  пример рабочий. Пробую сделать у себя в приложении тоже самое но при первой попытке как будто запускается `WhatsApp` и сразу же закрывается.  При последующий попытках - вообще ничего не происходит, единственная реакция - это строка в логах:

> V/WhatsApp: Total WhatsApp Contacts: 17

Я делаю это так:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = ContactUriHelper.getUriFromPhoneNumber(contact.getPhone().getNumber(), getApplicationContext());
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/2021"), //Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/_id")
            "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call");
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(intent);
```

`Uri` пробовал и строкой передавать и самим обьектом `uri` - ничего не зименилось.

`Uri` я получаю следующим образом

```
 public static Uri getUriFromPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, Context context) {
        Uri uri = null;
        String contactId = getContactIdByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, context);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(contactId)) {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID},
                    ContactsContract.Data.DATA2 + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{"Viber", contactId}, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                Log.wtf(TAG, cursor.toString());
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                        uri = Uri.parse(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
                        Log.d(TAG, "URI: " + uri.toString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return uri;
    }

    private static String getContactIdByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, Context context) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        String contactId = null;
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};

        Cursor cursor =
                contentResolver.query( uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        Log.wtf(TAG, "ContactID: " + contactId);
        return contactId;
    }
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А ид 2021 есть в контактах whatsapp-а?

Comment: что значит в контактах whatsapp-a ? я его из телефонной книги устройства достаю, я добавил в вопрос методы с помощью которых  я получаю   Uri,   а потом я делаю  uri.toString() и получаю строку которую потом подставляю в вызов WhatsApp'a

Comment: по ссылке ответа, который вы приводите, упоминают, что "only those _Ids whose MIME type is vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call"

Comment: можно конкретней, что нужно сделать, что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По ссылке говорят, что нужно отфильтровать записи по mimetype `"vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call"`
т.е.

```
public static Uri getUriFromPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, Context context) {
 Uri uri = null;
 String contactId = getContactIdByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, context);
 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(contactId)) {
  Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
   ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Data._ID
   },
   ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
   new String[] {
    "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call",
    contactId
   }, null);
  if (cursor != null) {
   Log.wtf(TAG, cursor.toString());
   while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
     uri = Uri.parse(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
     Log.d(TAG, "URI: " + uri.toString());
     break;
    }
   }
   cursor.close();
  }
 }
 return uri;
}
```

Comment: я полчается брал  Uri  для Viber а не для WhatsApp. Все заработало!

Comment: @KirillStoianov, большинство ошибок на внимательность :)